# Can't read json post method (jackson)

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson

I Have object Bill where i lisen @JsonRootName(value = "bill").
I have result Bill{siteId='null', billId='null'} where i make misstake ? 
my json

```
{
    "bill":
    {
        "siteId":"gkfhuj-00",
        "billId":"11b0309c-42b8-4d20-bd58-3e854f039287"
    }
}
```

my class Bill

```
@JsonRootName(value = "bill")
public class Bill {
    private final String siteId;
    private final String billId;

    public Bill(String siteId, String billId) {
        this.siteId = siteId;
        this.billId = billId;
    }


    public String getSiteId() {
        return siteId;
    }

    public String getBillId() {
        return billId;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Bill{" +
                "siteId='" + siteId + '\'' +
                ", billId='" + billId + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

My method where i lisen Json Object

```
    @PostMapping("/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity getJson(@RequestBody Bill bill) {

        System.out.println(bill.toString());

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: still null... dont work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably Jackson's "feature toggles". You need to enable [UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.html#UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE) in your `ObjectMapper`. So this should go somewhere into your `@Bean` configuration if you're using Spring:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
```

Comment: i add to my application.properties 
```
spring.jackson.deserialization.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE=true
```

now work fine.